# invertibility of non square matrix

Tags: matrices

I was looking at the properties of invertible matrix, and I came across this statement.

If $A$ is $m$ by $n$ matrix and the $rank$ of $A$ is equal to $m$, then $A$ has a right
inverse.

Can any give me a proof for this statement?

Comment: A map has a right inverse if and only if it is surjective. The rank of the matrix being equal to the number of rows means the induced linear map is surjective.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure I understand your terms. Could you explain more explicitly?

Comment: Which terms are you not sure you understand? Do you know that a matrix induces a linear map via multiplication of the matrix with a (column) vector?

Comment: @DanielFischer I was sure about the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A right inverse means that there exists some $B$ such that $AB = I$, in this case the identity is on $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$.

The fun fact here is that $\ker A^T = \ker (A A^T)$. Since ${\cal R} A = \mathbb{R}^m$, we have $\ker A^T = \{0\}$, that is, $A A^T$ is invertible.

To find $B$ above,  we try to solve $Ax = y$. Since ${\cal R} A = {\cal R} A A^T$, we can start by looking for a solution to $A (A^T z) = y$, and substitute back to get $x$ later.

Since $A A^T$ is invertible, we have $z = (A A^T) ^{-1} y$, and so $x = A^T (A A^T) ^{-1} y$, which suggests setting $B = A^T (A A^T) ^{-1}$.

It is easy to verify that $B = A^T (A A^T) ^{-1}$ is a right inverse of $A$.

Note that this is not, in general, unique. For example, suppose $C$ is such that ${\cal R} C \subset \ker A$, then we have $AC = 0$, and so $B+\lambda C$ is also a right inverse for any $\lambda$.

Comment: Since $RA=R^m$, we have ker$A^T$={0}, that is, $AA^T$ is invertible.

Comment: I'm not sure why $AA^T$ is invertible here

Comment: Well, since ${\cal R} A = {\cal R} (AA^T) = \mathbb{R}^m$, it is surjective, and since $\ker A^T = \ker (A A^T) = \{ 0 \}$, it is injective. Hence invertible. In fact, since the matrix $A A^T$ is square, either of the above conditions will suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it

Comment: Delighted to be able to help